# how can I make Xlsxwriter by default activate the headings in an Excel sheet?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I use the xlsxwriter package in Python to generate Excel files. This works perfectly fine, except one thing. When opening the files in Excel the row numbers and column headers are not shown. They can easily be activated in Excel through the View tab, then tick the 'Headings' box. How can I make them visible by default ? No function or attribute seems to exist for this in xlsxwriter.

Comment: I have headers if I run the [hello world example](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_hello_world.html). Please provide a [mcve] and show what you get and what you expect instead; also tell us what version of Excel you are using.

Answer (score 0):

To add header, you can use the write function like this:

```
 import xlsxwriter

 # Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
 workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses02.xlsx')
 worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

 # Add a bold format to use to highlight cells.
 bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

 worksheet.write('A1', 'Item', bold)
 worksheet.write('B1', 'Cost', bold)
```

See more:

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial02.html

Comment: thx much for the suggestion to try again with the simplest model. Made me see that there was still a line in the code to hide column headers and row numbers worksheet.hide_row_col_headers()

Comment: My pleasure. I suggest starting from the simplest, most minimal example, get the header working, then add more afterwards.

Comment: If you found this answer useful, please consider to mark it as the correct answer.